# Несколько человек общаются

Tags: числительные, множественное-число

Какие будут правильные формы для выражения:

> N человек общаются в чате

при N = 1, 2, 5, 21?

В частности интересует, будет `-ются` или `-етcя` для множественного числа.

Есть ли вообще смысл в таком предложении для N = 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 человек общается в чате.
2 человека общаются (общается) в чате.
5 человек общаются (общается) в чате.
21 человек общается в чате.

В случае "2 человека" и "5 человек" сказуемое может быть употреблено как в единственном, так и во множественном числе. Числительные, оканчивающиеся на один, требуют формы единственного числа сказуемого. Подробнее см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

Вариант "1 человек общается в чате" грамматически правилен, но вне контекста не имеет смысла. Впрочем, я вообще не могу придумать подходящий контекст. Но можно сказать:  "1 человек общается со мной в чате."

Answer (score 1):

Обща**ЮТ**ся,потому что действующие лица активны, нам важно не только их число, а то, что это личности.

А вот один человек общаться в чате не может, предложение смысла не имеет. Один может общаться с кем-то.

Если нужно универсальное клише, лучше оставить так:

В чате общается ... человек(а)

Comment: Универсальное не нужно. Можно различать для 1, 2, 5. Если исключить влияние смысла, то для 1 и для 21 текст будет идентичен?

Comment: На постановку сказуемого в форму единственного числа влияет стремление автора текста обратить внимание читателей на совместность действия действующих лиц, а также на количество, названное в подлежащем: 

На лекцию пришло именно пятьдесят человек, а не пятьдесят два.